# Add an object into an array with named fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have trouble trying to **add an object into an array** with JavaScript.
I have searched in other questions, but my problem is more specific.

This is my array:

```
dataGameDentro = [{ Name  : "EM1Aaa", Pontos : 7000 },{ Name  : "EM1B", Pontos : 400 }];
```

I am trying to add

```
var currentPoint = $('#points-final').html().toString();

dataGameDentro.push({Name:"e5", Pontos : currentPoint});
```

or

```
dataGameDentro.splice(dataGameDentro.length, 0, {Name:"e5", Pontos : currentPoint});
```

but it doesn't work. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: What's inside  $('#points-final').html() ?

Comment: More code please, array may be out of scope. Do you get an error?

Comment: What does _it doesn't work_ mean? What happens that you don't expect to happen, or what doesn't happen that you do expect to happen? The code shown looks okay: you can use `push()` to add an object to an array.

Comment: `dataGameDentro.push({Name:"e5", Pontos : currentPoint});` should work. Are you getting console errors? What is the output of the array when you use `push`?

Comment: This code works http://jsfiddle.net/5537wxh6/ ! Also your `.toString()`is unnecessary because `.html()` already returns a string. But perharps you want to have an Integer like the other values, in this case, take a look at `parseInt()` : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: @Miam84, it probably needs to be coerced to an integer based on the example array.

Comment: Which error are you recieving?

Comment: @Andy, you're probably right, but as a String it would not break the code through (if it's what `doesn't work` says...)

Comment: The rate this conversation is going I don't think we'll ever find out.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments on the question, the problem here is that your `Pontos` are stored as integer values, whereas the result of `.html()` is always a string value.

Naturally, you want to coerce the string value into an integer. The best way* of doing this in JS is using [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), like so:

```
var currentPoint = parseInt($('#points-final').html(), 10);

dataGameDentro.push({ Name: 'e5', Pontos: currentPoint });
```

I hope this clarifies things a bit.

*N.B. *There are faster ways of converting from a string to an integer, as shown by [these benchmarks](https://jsperf.com/number-vs-parseint-vs-plus/95), but `parseInt` is by far the most clear and reliable.*